# Libre Office - calculation to multiply two numbers together

Tags: libreoffice, calculation

I have a monthly spreadsheet with varying numbers of hours per day. I want to multiply each of the daily hours by 20 each time and create a formula so it does this automatically.

I can't work out how to do this so that the formula copies across each time and automatically gives the hours x 20. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome! In general, this is not difficult, in general, the formula looks like this `=20*SUM(range_of_cells_with_hours_per_day)`. That is, if you have the clock values, for example, in column D, then the formula will be `=20*SUM(D:D)`, and if, for example, in the range E2:K12, then `=20*SUM(E2:K12)`. The fact is that the values of the hours per day can be placed in the monthly sheet in several different ways. You didn't say how you did it in your spreadsheet. A screenshot that you would paste into your question would be very helpful in understanding your predicament.

Comment: Thank you. 

This is an example.

NUMBER OF HOURS

6 (hours) x 20 = 120, 
4 (hours) x 20 = 80,
8 (hours x 20 = 160,

etc. So each set of hours always needs to be multiplied by 20.

Comment: Where do you want the results to appear? Would you mind to [edit] your question and add an example? It could have the results manually inserted, just to show what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Let's recreate your example in Calc, starting with an empty sheet. In cell A1 enter "NUMBER OF HOURS". Put 6 in A2, 4 in A3, and 8 in A4. Easy so far, right?

Now, click on cell B2. Press <kbd>=</kbd>, click on cell A2, and then enter `*20` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The result should show as 120.

Next, click again on cell B2. See the dark square in the lower right hand corner of the cell? Click and drag it down to cell B4.

Here is the result:

```
NUMBER OF HOURS     
6   120
4   80
8   160
```